# Wrap associative array with non-associative array so that JavaScript gets correct format

Tags: javascript, php, drupal

I'm currently working with drupal and the Flowplayer API.

In Javascript, everything is pretty easy for me, but when it comes to PHP my noob knowledge is not sufficient enough.

What I need to make a flowplayer plugin work is a javascript structure like this:

```
                             "ads" : {
                                    "schedule" : [ {
                                        "position" : "pre-roll",
                                        "server" : {
                                            "type" : "direct",
                                            "timeoutInSeconds" : 5,
                                            "tag" : "http%3Asomething",
                                        }
                                    } ]
                                }
```

But with my php API

```
            'ads'=> array(
                  'scheudle'=>array(
                      'position'=>'pre-roll',
                      'server'=> array(
                          'type'=>'direct',
                          "timeoutInSeconds"=>5,
                          "tag"=>"httpsomething",
                      )

                  )
              )
```

I get JavaScript like this:

```
 "ads":{
    "scheudle":{  /*HERE NEEDS TO BE A WRAPPING [] ARRAY LIKE ABOVE */
       "position":"pre-roll",
       "server":{
           "type":"direct",
           "timeoutInSeconds":5,
           "tag":"http%3something"
       }
    }
},
```

How can I make my PHP output the correct js structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
'ads'=> array(
                  'scheudle'=>array(array(
                      'position'=>'pre-roll',
                      'server'=> array(
                          'type'=>'direct',
                          "timeoutInSeconds"=>5,
                          "tag"=>"httpsomething",
                      )

                  ))
              )
```